# Why are the first 514 blocks on testnet3 dated much earlier?

Tags: testnet, history

This is kind of an obscure question, but I'm curious.

In playing with Testnet (version 3), I noticed an odd jump in the block times.  Blocks [0](http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/b/0) through [513](http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/b/513) have block times from 2-3 February 2011.  Block [514](http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/b/514) is dated 25 May 2012 - over 15 months later.

Did the bitcoin developers mine blocks 0-513 in 2011 and then sit on them for over a year, or were they mined in 2012 and backdated for some reason?

For reference, as I learned from [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/9979/5757), testnet3 was adopted by [this commit](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/feeb761ba07af74a7cd78b8c8f7c2a961fd9ea1c).  I'm a little confused as to the exact date; `git log` appears to show it as 12 April 2012, while [github](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commits/feeb761ba07af74a7cd78b8c8f7c2a961fd9ea1c) gives 25 May 2012.  (Maybe the discrepancy has to do with when the change was made in whose repo?)  The first release with testnet3 was 0.7.0, [released 17 September 2012](http://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.7.0).

Comment: As speculation, maybe the blocks were intentionally backdated in order to see how the difficult adjustment algorithm would respond to a long gap in block times?  I know many of the early testnet blocks intentionally include unusual features as a sort of regression test for client implementations, so maybe this is somehow another example of that.